# Laravel Jetstream User Profile Page is Empty

Tags: laravel, profile, laravel-jetstream

I have installed "laravel/jetstream": "^2.9" on "laravel/framework": "^8.75". When I accessed Profile Information page, it doesn't load necessary information into relevant form fields.Please help me with this isses.[image: Profile Information page]

Even I have tried reinstalling Jetstream separately. Problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

publish livewire config

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=livewire:config
```

verify the path to livewire  in config\livewire.php

```
 'asset_url' => '/../yourpath/public',
 'app_url' => '/../yourpath/public',
```

inspect the result web page and verify the path for livewire.js file is correct

```
<script src="/../yourpath/public/vendor/livewire/livewire.js?id=de3fca26689cb5a39af4" data-turbo-eval="false" data-turbolinks-eval="false" ></script>
```

i think that you production is not in the root directory ,for me it was in a subfolder so i get this problem
hope it work for you

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Issue was exactly with livewire variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your Console you probably have a console error that livewire is not working properly. Usually the following command is missing at this point

```
php artisan livewire:publish --assets
```

Let me know if this helps

All the best!

Comment: Thanks.
I tried it too. But still no luck.